# Can't create partition

Tags: partitioning, windows, kubuntu, gparted

Why it doesn't allow me to resize my partition?

[image: GParted screenshot]

I want to create separate partition for windows (7) but no idea how. /:

Comment: What's the exact error? I cannot see your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lock icon means the partition is in use and therefore you can't modify it. Boot into a live environment to make your changes.